# Connect to pseudoterminal (same user) from lost session

Tags: terminal, tty

I was running several large processes at once, and my PC froze (I suspect due to heat, its a laptop, and the fan was at maximum for several minutes just prior to locking up). The mouse cursor moved, but clicks had no effect. I could still hear sound from one of the processes, but it was visually frozen. I hit ctrl-alt-f2 as a last ditch effort to get it to do something before a hard reboot, and it switched to tty2. So, I switched back to 1, logged in, and ran startx.

My `who` output:

```
nexus@Lithium ~ $ who
nexus    tty1         2014-02-26 11:14
nexus    tty7         2014-02-20 09:50 (:0)
nexus    pts/0        2014-02-26 10:21 (:0.0)
nexus    pts/2        2014-02-26 11:11 (:0)
nexus    pts/3        2014-02-26 11:23 (:1)
```

I figured out the pts sessions are where I had the terminal emulator open.  I would like to reconnect to pts/0, and be able to view and use (save and close) the process it is running.  Is this possible?  Just want to open a new terminal somehow and get it to "take over" or "emulate" or "mirror" the original term.  I can still hear the music in the background from the game in pts/0, and firefox is still running under that tty as well, so that I can't run a new firefox process.

Comment: `screen` might be able to do this.

Comment: tmux is another option.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool `retty` which is supposed to be able to do that. Have a look at [its web page](http://pasky.or.cz/dev/retty/) and [its Ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/retty.1.html).